# How to merge/combine the values of two javascript obj properties

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of object:

```
  [
    {
      patientId: 587278335,
      firstAppDate: '2012-04-21',
      lastAppDate: '2017-04-17',
      referral: 'Y',
    },
    {obj2}, {obj3}
  ];
```

I am trying to combine the first appointment and last appointment dates into a single obj or array, is there an easy way to do it?

Update:

Desired result-->

`['2012-04-21', '2017-04-17' ]`

Comment: Please clarify your question. The sample data is insufficient. What is your desired result? Provide an example of it?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, my desired result would be something like: ['2012-04-21', '2017-04-17' ]

Comment: `arr.map((o) => [o.firstAppDate, o lastAppDate])`

Comment: Do you want to get the `firstAppDate` and `lastAppDate` for all the objects that belong to the `array` or just for the first one?

Comment: for all objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) this way to get new objects with only the desired properties.

```js
let data = [
  {patientId:587278335, firstAppDate:'2012-04-21', lastAppDate:'2017-04-17', referral:'Y'},
  {patientId:587278336, firstAppDate:'2012-04-19', lastAppDate:'2017-07-27', referral:'X'},
  {patientId:587278337, firstAppDate:'2014-01-11', lastAppDate:'2018-03-22', referral:'Z'}
];

let res = data.map(({firstAppDate, lastAppDate}) => ({firstAppDate, lastAppDate}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

If you need `arrays` instead of the `objects` then replace the `map()` expression by next one:

```
let res = data.map(({firstAppDate, lastAppDate}) => [firstAppDate, lastAppDate]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = [{
  patientId: 587278335,
  firstAppDate: '2012-04-21',
  lastAppDate: '2017-04-17',
  referral: 'Y',
}];

const result = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push(curr.firstAppDate);
  acc.push(curr.lastAppDate);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello mate hope this might help you

If you want to merge two objects then,

```
var o1 = { a: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2 };
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(o1);  // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, target object itself is changed.
```

if you are willing to merge two object properties then

```
    let obj = {
      patientId: 587278335,
      firstAppDate: '2012-04-21',
      lastAppDate: '2017-04-17',
      referral: 'Y',
    },

let resultDesired = [obj.firstAppDate, obj.lastAppDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, below code may help.
Your Question Problem looks something like this:

```
 const obj2 = {};
 const obj3 = {};
 const myObjectArray = [
    {
      patientId: 587278335,
      firstAppDate: '2012-04-21',
      lastAppDate: '2017-04-17',
      referral: 'Y',
    },
    obj2, obj3
  ];
```

And here is the solution to your problem:

```
 const {firstAppDate,lastAppDate} = myObjectArray[0];

 const newArray = [];
 newArray.push(firstAppDate,lastAppDate);
 console.log(newArray);
```

**Explanation:**

I am using ES6 De-structuring concept to get the values(firstAppDate and lastAppDate) from the given array's first Object.

Then I am creating a new empty array by the name newArray and pusing the values in that

Hope this helps.
Thank You :)